# PHP concatenate names and update SQL field

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

Firstly, here is my code

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM Members WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$check = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($check['fullname'] == 0) {
$qry1 = "SELECT CONCAT( fname, ' ', lname ) AS firstlast FROM Members WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."'";
$result1 = mysql_query($qry1);
$qry2 = "UPDATE Members SET fullname = '$result1'"; }
```

I am trying to do the following:-

1. Check if the 'fullname' field from the Members table is 0 (which is
   the default value) based on the member_id
2. If it is, then concatenate the fname and lname fields into one
   string, with a space in between
3. Take this concatenated string and place it back into the Members
   table in the 'fullname' field

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your last query (`$qry2`) will set ALL records to the same `fullname`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing your problem, you could do all of that in one query:

```
UPDATE Members SET fullname=CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) 
      WHERE fullname=0 AND member_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."'
```

Comment: That'll update *everyone's* `fullname` field, not just the current user.

Comment: Agreed, I updated the answer. However, OP doesn't state the problem and also updates all records ;-).

Comment: "Check if the 'fullname' field from the Members table is 0 (which is the default value) **based on the member_id**" ;)

Comment: Works perfectly! And soooo much simpler than the mess I was originally trying to do. Thanks a lot everyone :-)

Comment: @Chris, read up on MySQL tutorials. You can do quite a lot in your database. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can quite easily achieve this with a single query:

```
UPDATE `Members` 
SET `fullname` = CONCAT(`fname`, ' ', `lname`) 
WHERE `member_id` = '".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."' 
  AND `fullname` = 0 
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with only one query.

```
$query = "UPDATE Members SET fullname = CONCAT( fname, ' ', lname )
          WHERE member_id = {$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}
          AND fullname = 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$qry1 = "UPDATE Members SET fullname = CONCAT( fname, ' ', lname ) WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."'";
```

Comment: That doesn't check if `fullname` == 0.

Comment: Thanks for notice but i thought user checked in program that before running this query like if($check['fullname'] == 0) { --- }

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in just one query, (*without calling select once*)

```
UPDATE  Members a
SET     a.fullName = IF(fullname = 0, CONCAT(fname, ' ',lname), fullName)
WHERE   member_ID = 'memberIDHERE'
```